# Calling the Moodle Rest-API

Tags: node.js, moodle, moodle-api

I am unclear on how to make any API calls to my Moodle web-server from my Node.JS LMS. I already setup the Moodle server and created the user with the correct role, but I don't know how to call it from my project. I'm currently just trying to extract course data from a course with an ID of 1 using core_course_get_contents. I am currently just working in javascript.

I tried making a fetch call from the client, but I was just met with various errors. I decided to use the server I'm working on as a proxy to get around the CORS limitations, but now I'm getting certificate errors or a bad JSON error.

Comment: Please post the exact errors you are getting and the code you are using to make the API request. Did you check to see if any logs are being generated?

Comment: @user1279887 Sorry for the late response. I haven't seen any logs detailing the error. Upon further inspection, I'm getting a different error than I was a few days ago, but I'll still supply what I'm doing. [Link to my code and error.](https://pastebin.com/yePsYTz5)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an API at Moodle. It calls Web-Services. To create and enable it follow these steps:

1. Enable **REST protocol** `/admin/settings.php?section=webserviceprotocols`
2. Create new service `/admin/webservice/service.php?id=0`
3. Create a token `/admin/webservice/tokens.php?action=create` and attach it to `Web Service` from step 2
4. Go to **External Web Services list** at `/admin/settings.php?section=externalservices` and add an external function to a needle service from step 2. You can use [core Moodle external functions](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions) or [create an own one](https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/subsystems/external/writing-a-service).
5. Create a request with params. [Read here how](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client)

### API Manager Plugin

Yes, this is a quest, but you can use [local_wsmanager plugin](https://github.com/liliapro/moodle-local_wsmanager) to manage Moodle Web-Services/APIs from one place.